# Copy secret variable in Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I have a fairly simple pipeline where `subproject_test` is not a secret, but `openshift_token_test` is a secret.

```
steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=project]$(subproject_test)"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=openshift_token;issecret=true]$(openshift_token_test)"
  displayName: Set test branch variables

- bash: |
    echo ${PROJECT}
    echo ${#OPENSHIFT_TOKEN}
  displayName: Show vars
```

the output  of `Show vars` always shows 0 as length of `OPENSHIFT_TOKEN` variable, while `PROJECT` variable shown correctly. I did try adding `env` and mapping secret to it - did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

For people who meet the similar question to refer to.

This situation is totally expected.

> Why this happens?

The usage is not correct.

${variable} is a usage of bash script, it is as same as $variable in bash. {} is just a  disambiguation mechanism in bash, and it is not a variable usage in DevOps pipeline.

Official document clearly clarify why in this situation nothing will be put in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#usage-4

> When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will be saved
> as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables aren't passed into
> tasks as environment variables and must instead be passed as inputs.

[image]

It is the example, it also describe how to use the output variable correctly in same job:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#examples-1

How to use the output variables correctly in every situation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with using `$(OPENSHIFT_TOKEN)` instead of `${OPENSHIFT_TOKEN}`